# Remove Requested URL, Version Information and ASP.NET version from HTTP 404

Tags: c#, vb.net, http, iis, http-status-code-404

When hitting a HTTP 404 server error, the web page shows **Requested URL** and **Version Information**. Is there a way to remove this information? [image]

I have seen that you can do this via creating a custom error page for 404 using the following code in the web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>
       <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
          <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="xxx.htm" responseMode="File" />
       </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

I have also seen this can also be done via IIS. What way is best practice, IIS or web.config?

Is the only way to remove this information by using a custom error page?

If I were to do it via IIS, how would I go about doing this?

I am currently running on Version 10.0.19041.1 of IIS.

Comment: You should provide a proper custom not found page in your web app: this is the only route that gives you full control. (Note some of the config options will redirect on 404 to a page which is not  IMHO a great user experience).

Comment: Best case is handling the errors yourself, that way you get to decide how far you inform your visitors. And maybe provide contact details in case the problem persists.

Comment: The fragment you showed is using IIS custom error page feature to hide the default error page. So what do you mean by “via IIS”? I guess you misunderstood the concepts and asked an invalid question. Maybe start from an IIS administration book and learn from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom error messages to IIS by adding an  element to the  element in the Web.config file for your site, application, or URL.

About how to add a custom error page in iis you can refer to this link:

[How to add a custom error page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/).